# How can I make two user models, "Customer" and "Dealer" with different table in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm New in Django and I'm working on a project in which I want to make separate Login, Logout, Verification and Reset Password apis with JWT
I'm trying to get different tables so that if one tries to login in Dealer Id from Customer id, then it won't accept it and so the person has to register on Dealer api too
My models.py is like this

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin)
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, username, email, mobile_number, account_role, account_type, role, address, state, city, pincode, password = None):
            user = self.model(username = username, email = self.normalize_email(email), mobile_number = mobile_number, account_role = account_role, account_type = account_type, role = role, address = address, state = state, city = city, pincode = pincode)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user

        def create_superuser(self, username, email, mobile_number, account_role, account_type, role, address, state, city, pincode, password = None):
            if password is None:
                raise TypeError('Password Should Not Be None')
            user = self.create_user(username, email, password, mobile_number, account_role, account_type, role, address, state, city, pincode)
            user.is_superuser = True
            user.is_staff = True
            user.save()
            return user

    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
        mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
        account_role = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Customer')
        account_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        role = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'mobile_number', 'account_type', 'role', 'address', 'state', 'city', 'pincode',]

        objects = UserManager()

        def tokens(self):
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
            return{
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token)
            }

    class Customer(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
        mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
        account_role = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Customer')
        account_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        role = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'mobile_number', 'account_type', 'role', 'address', 'state', 'city', 'pincode',]

        objects = UserManager()
        def tokens(self):
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
            return{
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token)
            }
        

    class Dealer(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
        mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
        account_role = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Dealer')
        account_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        role = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
        is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'mobile_number', 'account_type', 'address', 'state', 'city', 'pincode',]

        objects = UserManager()

        def tokens(self):
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
            return{
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token)
            }
```

Comment: You can just add users to two different `Groups`. `Customer` and `Dealer`. Then give each group their specific permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In the `django-ish` world, it is often a good idea to keep your different types of `users` on the same table.

So, your `customer` and `dealer` can reside on the table(i.e. `your_user` table). However, you can define two different groups/types for them respectively, though in order to distinguish them.

Depending on the `user_types`, your `login API/function` can act according to your choices. Such as, you can let them log into the system in different ways, can have separate verifications, etc.

You can still have multiple `user types`, but generally speaking it’s not a good idea to store `authentication` information across multiple models/tables. Treat this model as an `account` rather than a `user`. Meaning, all users need an account to log in.